# How to take in python element-wise logarithm of a np. array to have the output with the same array dimension?

Tags: python

if `H` is positive values:

```
H = array([[1.23804376, 2.20570418], [3.58034804, 2.71199949]])
```

and I want to calculate `A = log2(1 + H_abs)` such that A have the same dimensions as H

always gives error: `Only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Answer (score 1):

Then just do that, vectorially:

```
import numpy as np

H = np.array([[1.23804376, 2.20570418], [3.58034804, 2.71199949]])

A = np.log2(1 + H)  # note the use of np.log2
```

*If you need the absolute value of `H`: `A = np.log2(1 + abs(H))`.*

Output:

```
array([[1.16223825, 1.6806413 ],
       [2.19545723, 1.89219651]])
```

Shape:

```
A.shape == H.shape
# True
```